# Looking for an app or SaaS to allow me to plan the tasks I need to do

Tags: productivity, saas, jira, trello

Ok, a little context:

I have used Trello, Todoist, Jira, Asana, Notion, Target Process and a few others.

I believe the ones that are more similar to what I am looking for are Trello and Todoist, as Jira, Asana and Target process seem overkill for this.

Basically what I am looking for is an app or SaaS that allows me to easily create tasks (need to be synced between my multiple devices - windows and android support).

Some tasks are one-off, and some tasks are recursive. Things like:

- Need to do X (with a deadline of September 30, or no deadline)
- Need to do Y every Monday
- Need to do Z every month on the 20th

Trello works very well for non-recurring tasks, and Todoist works well for recurring tasks.

I like the ability to organize Trello in lists within boards, and I could even use a list for non-recurring, another for weekly, another for monthly, whatever.

I just need the system to be easy to use so I can add tasks from my mobile so I don't forget them, and can be sortable (by the due date, priority, whatever).

The goal of the recurring tasks is that I can archive / mark as done today for the current month, but it'll show up again as a task next month.

Maybe I am asking for too many things, but I just need an easy way to take notes of what I need to do. I have never explored Notion deeply so I honestly don't know if it has similar features or not.

Any suggestions will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I have been using [Remember the Milk](https://www.rememberthemilk.com) since 2006 and I love it. I use it for both my personal and professional life. There is a free and a paid version. There is a website as well as apps for Android, iOS and smart watches. There are also a bunch of integrations with other services.

What I like the most with Remember the Milk is the ease of custom filtering and sorting. I don't know if it's a feature of just the paid version but one can add so called Smart lists which are essentially [saved custom searches](https://www.rememberthemilk.com/help/answer/basics-search-advanced). With a paid account there is also limited scripting abilities, enabling the user to automate many tasks.

What's added on the website is synced to the mobile app and vice versa. I think there is a limitation of sync speed in the free version, like one sync once per hour instead of unlimited (but I'm not sure since I have had a paid version for so long).

Since Remember the Milk isn't meant to be a full project management tool, it lacks some features such as dependencies between tasks.